# I load a form in an ajax div, but how to I load the form query result into that same div?

Tags: ajax, forms

A form loads into my ajax div, but once the user submits the form data, the entire screen reloads the form result when ideally it should just load into that same ajax div.

My current code for my working ajax looks like this:

```
<!-- starts ajax code -->    
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var everyone = document.getElementById('everyone'),
            searching = document.getElementById('searching');

        everyone.onclick = function() {
            loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone');
            everyone.className = 'filterOptionActive';
            searching.className = 'filterOption';
        }

        searching.onclick = function() {
            loadXMLDoc('indexSearching');        
            searching.className = 'filterOptionActive';
            everyone.className = 'filterOption';
        }

        function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("leftCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }

            function get_query(){
              var url = location.href;
              var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
              for(var i = 0, result = {}; i < qs.length; i++){
                qs[i] = qs[i].split('=');
                result[qs[i][0]] = decodeURIComponent(qs[i][1]);
              }
              return result;
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","../browse/" + pageName + ".php?user=" + get_query()['user'],true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
    }
    </script>
    <!-- ends ajax script -->
```

How can I use this code to ensure this form loads into the ajax window?

```
<form name="searchLocations" action="/indexSearchingSubmit.php" method="POST">
        <select name="locationName">
            <?php 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT locationName FROM tbl_locations ORDER BY locationName ASC");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['locationName'] . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for example, in your form, you should not submit it by replacing:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

=> and do the thing locally using JavaScript function:

```
<input type="button" value="Load" onclick="loadXMLDoc('/indexSearchingSubmit.php'); return false;">
```

When AJAX returns, it uses as specifies your js code:

```
document.getElementById("leftCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

to write the response to the div leftCont. Without change your current entire page.

If you want to pass parameters to ajax call, il will be more complicated.

#### This is an IE checked example, using [formserialize()](https://code.google.com/p/form-serialize/) to get form data:

```
<html>
<!-- starts ajax code -->  
<head>
<script>
function formserialize (form) {
  if (!form || form.nodeName !== "FORM") {
    return;
  }
  var i, j, q = [];
  for (i = form.elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
    if (form.elements[i].name === "") {
      continue;
    }
    switch (form.elements[i].nodeName) {
      case 'INPUT':
        switch (form.elements[i].type) {
          case 'text':
          case 'hidden':
          case 'password':
          case 'button':
          case 'reset':
          case 'submit':
            q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
            break;
          case 'checkbox':
          case 'radio':
            if (form.elements[i].checked) {
              q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
            }                                               
            break;
        }
        break;
      case 'file':
        break; 
      case 'TEXTAREA':
        q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
        break;
       case 'SELECT':
         switch (form.elements[i].type) {
           case 'select-one':
             q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
             break;
           case 'select-multiple':
             for (j = form.elements[i].options.length - 1; j >= 0; j = j - 1) {
               if (form.elements[i].options[j].selected) {
                 q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].options[j].value));
               }
             }
             break;
           }
           break;
         case 'BUTTON':
           switch (form.elements[i].type) {
             case 'reset':
             case 'submit':
             case 'button':
               q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
               break;
           }
           break;
         }
  }
  return q.join("&");
}

function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
{
  var xmlhttp, formdata;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("leftCont").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  var url;
  if(pageName)
  {
    url = "../browse/" + pageName + ".php?user=" + get_query()['user'];
  }
  else
  {
    url = window.location.href;
  }
  formdata = formserialize(document.forms["searchLocations"]);
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send(formdata);
}

function get_query(){
  var url = location.href;
  var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for(var i = 0, result = {}; i < qs.length; i++){
    qs[i] = qs[i].split('=');
    result[qs[i][0]] = decodeURIComponent(qs[i][1]);
  }
  return result;
}

window.onload = function () {
  var everyone = document.getElementById('everyone'),
     searching = document.getElementById('searching');

  everyone.onclick = function() {
    loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone');
    everyone.className = 'filterOptionActive';
    searching.className = 'filterOption';
  }

  searching.onclick = function() {
    loadXMLDoc('indexSearching');  
    searching.className = 'filterOptionActive';
    everyone.className = 'filterOption';
  }
}
</script>
<!-- ends ajax script -->
</head>
<body>
<form name="searchLocations" action="/indexSearchingSubmit.php" method="POST">
<select name="locationName">
<?php 
  //
  // define MySQL query params before to do this:
  //...
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT locationName FROM tbl_locations ORDER BY locationName ASC");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['locationName'] . "</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Load" onclick="loadXMLDoc(); return false;" />
<input type="text" name="myname" value="Elaine" />
</form>

<div id="everyone"></div>
<div id="searching"></div>
<div id="leftCont" style="background-color: gold; width: 600px; height: 200px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I am now able to submit the form (thanks), but as you said, the form parameters are not being received into the ajax window - help?